# UIView inside UIScrollView not getting touch events

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

My view hierarchy looks like this:

```
-UIScrollView
---UIView
------CustomUIView
------CustomUIView
```

I have implemented `touchesBegan` in CustomUIView, but it's not getting called.

Can someone please tell me how I can get my CustomUIView to detect touches?

Comment: I tested the same hierarchy and it seems to be ok. Are these hidden views or have their `userInteractionEnabled = NO;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have solved this now but I had a similar problem and solved it so hopefully my experience can help anyone else with a similar issue.

In my case I had exactly the same setup my CustomUIView was capturing the touch events. In order to have UIView receive any touch events I needed to make a call to

```
[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
```

from the CustomUIView. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following and check:

```
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
```